# Facebook connect help android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I wanted to create a Facebook application for my android. I followed the instruction in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android. I have cloned  the github repository and followed all the page said. but I got confused at keytool section. Should I run the keytool command using git or using the command prompt? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need of generating keytool for facebook..without using keytool we can get FB,refer the GitHub source.